# Is it possible? Triple boot with 2OS'S on first hdd & 1OS on second hdd

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have Windows 10 & LinuxMint installed on 1 hdd/sda (3partitions-1 for windows. 2 for linux / & swap)

i want to install UBUNTU 16 as a 3rd OS on my second disk /sdb. My question now is:
What is the best way to do this?

Should i just install UBUNTU 16 on the second harddrive/sdb and make sure the mbr is installed on that second harddrive(while installing ubuntu)
And than after that boot into my LINUX MINT and use GRUB CUSTOMIZER to recognize the second hdd/sdb so it will show 3 OS's to boot up from in my Grub-Menu ?

I hope somebody can help me with this

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If BIOS just make sure second grub is on sdb, but keep sda as main booting drive and run sudo update-grub in main install. If UEFI last install overwrites /EFI/ubuntu. Back up ESP - efi system partition. But better to manually turn off os-prober and create your own boot stanza in 40_custom. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: @waltinator I haven't read any of those, and haven't had issues with dual-booting. Even after having to repair GRUB via a chroot.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, it doesn't matter what hard drives you put OSes on.
When booting two or more Linux distros, the main thing to remember is that if the distros use different GRUB installations, only the GRUB on the first partition on the drive booted first will run. As GRUB's configuration is generally updated from the distro that installed it, every time there is a kernel update on the other distro, you will have to boot into the first and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Thankyou for your quick response! I understand! Just one question..: so it does appear in the GRUB-CUSTOMIZER menu, so that im able to boot the second hdd? Nomatter what hdd i install it on? (I mean, when i boot it from my linux mint -first grub- hdd/sda?) as i explained? I need specifics about my situation haven 2 os's installed on the 1st en 1 os in the second hdd

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with Grub-customizer, but assuming it is just a frontend for the terminal-based GRUB utilities, it should have no problem. When I dual-booted Debian and Windows 7, they were on separate hard drives, but `update-grub` just detected the Windows drive.

Comment: @mchid Thankyou! I think i got it figured out! And i guess i left somethin out my question cause: My BIOS automatically boots the First hdd/sda cause i havent installed ubuntu on the second hdd/sda yet! But! Even when i install it (if i choose to install mbr on second harddrive) my PC(bios) will still automatically boot up the first hdd/sda am i right? Which will boot grub detecting only windows & linux mint! So i got to configure Grub(update-grub) on my LINUX MINT os (installed on the first hdd/sda) instead of 2nd hdd/sdb to make it appear when i reboot afterwards? Is this correct?

Comment: You need to tell your BIOS which drive you want it to boot first. All the GRUB configuration in the world won't help if the BIOS doesn't look on the right drive for a boot manager.

Comment: I dont think you fully understand! I ALLREADY HAVE WINDOWS & LINUX MINT INSTALLED ON THE FIRST (so grub is also installed on the first)  so if i install UBUNTU on the second+mbr on the second, and boot my first hdd from my BIOS it will load the old GRUB of hdd1 (from linux mint)

Comment: I don't need to understand specific situations. Whatever disk is booted first in BIOS, the GRUB it installs will be used.

Comment: Just need to add that if one plan to hibernate with Ubuntu then they really need separate Swap per ubuntu and will need to update `/etc/fstab` to comment all other Swap partitions which Ubuntu adds by default